# MySQL STR_TO_DATE Returns NULL with %p

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone explain why the first two return NULL?

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2022/12/11 08:10AM','%Y/%m/%d %H:%i%%p'); -- returns null
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2022/12/11 08:10 AM','%Y/%m/%d %H:%i% %p'); -- returns null
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2022/12/11 08:10','%Y/%m/%d %H:%i%'); -- returns "2022-12-11 08:10:00"
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized there is an extra %. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this two format as the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) said:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2022/12/11 08:10 AM','%Y/%m/%d %h:%i%p')
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2022/12/11 08:10:00 AM','%Y/%m/%d %r')
```

Answer (score 1):

%H is for 24 hour times which is not compatible with am/pm. Try using %h